# PGSQL delete cascade

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, ddl

there are my tables :

```
create table location (
    nom text primary key,
    adresse text
);
create table groupe (nom text primary key);
create table groupelocation (
    nomGroupe text references groupe (nom) on delete cascade,
    nomLocation text references location (nom) on delete cascade,
    primary key(nomGroupe, nomLocation)
);
insert into groupe values('groupe');
insert into location values('location', 'là bas');
insert into groupelocation values('groupe', 'location');
```

I want when i delete somethng in the group's table, delete all location which are associated but i can't find a solution :/
I've tried to do this : `create rule deletelocations as on delete to groupe do instead (delete from (select location natural join groupelocation where old.nom = nomGroupe));` but this wont work :/ Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres does not support supplying CASCADE to DELETE statements but it has support for cascading deletes at the table creation time.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtable.html

> CASCADE Delete any rows referencing the deleted row, or update the
>   value of the referencing column to the new value of the referenced
>   column, respectively.

Comment: It's so hard :o is there no any other solutions easier ? Like using rules ? I don't understand why my rule won't work :s

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, i've created a small plpgsql function to fix this problem

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION deletelocation()
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
    idloc int;
    curs refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN curs FOR SELECT location.id FROM location except SELECT location.id FROM location JOIN groupelocation ON location.id = groupelocation.idLocation;
    LOOP
        FETCH curs INTO idloc;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        DELETE FROM location WHERE id = idloc;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE curs; 
    RETURN '';
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```